# org-agenda buffer no longer shows agenda items

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I recently decided to redo my entire org setup and make it more efficient. I used to have .org files all over my machine, but they now reside in 2 folders:

```
~/work/org
~/personal/org
```

I reset where org-mode looks for agenda files with

```
;; set agenda files
(setq org-agenda-files (quote ("~/work/org"
                   "~/personal/org")))
```

However, when I pull up the todo list (`C-c a t`), I get errors of the form:

```
Non-existent agenda file [filename]. [R]emove from list or [A]bort?
```

for files that were in the old list. If I remove all these files, I eventually get an *Org Agenda* buffer that simply shows:

```
Global list of TODO items of type: ALL
Available with `N r': (0)[ALL]
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you eval'ed `setq org-agenda-files` after you change your init file?

Comment: Look at the value of `org-agenda-files`.

Comment: See my answer in a related thread that discusses how to set this variable using `org-agenda-file-regexp`:  http://superuser.com/a/702079/206164

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your comments. Yes, I eval'ed the expression. How do I check the value of `org-agenda-files` exactly?

Comment: My link above discusses how this variable is set each time it is needed with a function with the same name.

Comment: lawlist, I tried what you mentioned in the link above. Maybe I'm not following you. I added `(setq org-agenda-files (list "~/work/org/"))` to my `.emacs` and reloaded the file. In theory, the org files in that directory should now be crawled, right? But I still see nothing when I pull up the agenda.

Comment: What happens when you evaluate the function `(org-agenda-files)` -- i.e., what is the result that is displayed in your `*Messages*` buffer?  For example, my result looks like this:  `("/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.todo")`  Also, please let us know what you have for the `org-agenda-file-regexp`.  An example, is this:  `(setq org-agenda-files (list "~/"))` and `(setq org-agenda-file-regexp "\\`[^.].*\\.org\\|.todo\\'")`

Comment: It looks like I get `nil`. Is that possible?

Comment: At the very least, you should have gotten `~/work/org/` after running the function.  Why not try backing up everything, and doing a fresh install with just 3 lines in your `.emacs` file:  `(require 'org)`, `(setq org-agenda-files (list "~/"))`, and `(setq org-agenda-file-regexp "\`[^.].*\\.org\\|.todo\\'")`.  And put a couple of .org or .todo files in your home directory, and then run the function `(org-agenda-files)`:   `M-x eval-expression RET (org-agenda-files) RET` and report back with your results.  When posting a comment, please use `@lawlist` so that stackoverflow sends me an email.

Comment: @lawlist, looks like I found the bug (see fniessen's solution below). Thanks very much for your help though :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ensure you don't have org-agenda-files set in a "customize" block in your .Emacs file. This is a common source of errors.

Comment: Hey @fniessen, I'm an emacs n00b. Not sure what a `customize' block is. Can you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: Look for such a block in your .emacs file:
    (custom-set-variables
    ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
    ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
    ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
    ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
    '(org-...))

Comment: Ah, I see. I have some lines that say `(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(org-agenda-files nil))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )` Sorry for the bad editing. But does that help?

Comment: Yes, I think so: you set org-agenda-files to nil (that is, an empty list). Comment that line -- but pay attention to the extra parenthesis, and restart your Emacs. Then, you other spot where you set org-agenda-files should be the authoritative one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(setq org-agenda-files
      (append
       (file-expand-wildcards "~/work/org/*.org")
       (file-expand-wildcards "~/personal/org/*.org")))
```

Comment: Hey @artscan, I tried this but still have the same error. Any ideas? Can I give you any output that might help figure out what is wrong?

Comment: Give me the output of command `(describe-variable 'org-agenda-files)`

Comment: I did `M-x describe-variables org-agenda-files` and got `org-agenda-files is a variable defined in 'org.el'.
Its value is nil`. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: It should be not nil, e.g. `("~/work/org/emacs.org" "~/personal/org/budget.org" ...)`. In my case the function `file-expand-wildcards` returns list of .org-files in directory. You can begin from `(setq org-agenda-files (quote ("~/work/org/foo.org")))` and should get  `...Its value is ("~/work/org/foo.org")`.

Comment: Hi @artscan, I think fniessen found what was wrong (though I am sure other things are wrong as well) :-)